# OpenGL : Objects that are far away appearing as black

Tags: opengl, 3d

So I'm currently trying to figure out a reason for the black artifact as shown in the following screenshot.

What could it possibly me? The black area seems to be roughly in the same spot of the screen as I move around the scene.. it seems to be depth-related, but if that's the reason, then I wonder why the skybox works just fine.

Does this problem seem familiar to anybody? Could it be some kind of opengl setting?

[image: The strange artefact in question]

Comment: Have you got the far clipping planes set correctly and is there enough precision in the depth buffer?

Comment: To check for a depth buffer problem, please post how you setup your projection matrix (or the data provided to glFrustum if you are using it)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a mipmapping problem. Should have been a bit obvious, the object is rendered but as black. Upon further testing the black polygons rendered was still affected by fog, and on some irrlicht forum someone had a similar problem which turned out to be mipmapping.

Using GL_NEAREST on the textures for the filters fixed everything.